# How to pass a spaced path from robocopy output to a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I'm using the following script which outputs from robocopy all file names (with full paths) and their creation dates located in "H:\Backup" folder and if the total size of all files exceeds 100GB it deletes the oldest file.

```
REM @echo off

set "targetFolder=H:\Backup"
set "folderMaxSize=100"

for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('
robocopy "%targetFolder%" "%targetFolder%" /l /nocopy /is /s /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /ts
^| sort
') do call :process_dir %%b
goto :eof

:process_dir


set "PREVB="
for /F "tokens=3" %%B in ('
dir /S /-C "%targetFolder%"
') do (
call set "BYTES=%%PREVB%%"
set "PREVB=%%B"
)
set "BYTES_GIGA=%BYTES:~,-9%"
set "BYTES_ONES=%BYTES:~-9%"
if not defined BYTES_GIGA set "BYTES_GIGA=0"
set /A "BYTES_ONES=1%BYTES_ONES%%%1000000000"
if %BYTES_ONES% GTR 0 set /A "BYTES_GIGA+=1"


if %BYTES_GIGA% GTR %folderMaxSize% (
echo "%targetFolder%" - size %BYTES_GIGA% GB, deleting oldest file: %1
del %1
) else (
echo "%targetFolder%" - size is less than %folderMaxSize% GB. No action needed.
exit
)

goto :eof
```

This code work flawlessly if there is no spaces in the path. The problem begins when the path to the file has a spacebar, f.e. "H:\Backup\Data\Folder Name\file123.dat" in that case I get "set "PREVB=H:\Backup\Data\Folder".

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Change `%1` to `"%*"`, or change `call :process_dir %%b` to `call :process_dir "%%b"` and `%1` to `"%~1"`.

Comment: … and add option `delims=` to the `for /F` loop…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example:

```
set s=v w x y z

for /F %%a in ("%s%") do echo %%a

[OUTPUT]
v w x y z
```

when you use `for /f` and assign a variable (say `%%a`) the whole input is assigned to your variable.

Using `"tokens=..."` you can split your input and assign every space-delimited* part to a different variable:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%a in ("%s%") do echo %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e

[OUTPUT]
v,w,x,y,z
```

**(different delimiters can be specified using `delims`)*

you can also skip some token:

```
for /F "tokens=2,4" %%a in ("%s%") do echo %%a,%%b

[OUTPUT]
w,y
```

Using `*` you can assign *remaining tokens* to a single variable:

```
for /F "tokens=2,*" %%a in ("%s%") do echo %%a,%%b

[OUTPUT]
w,x y z
```

In this last example token 1 is ignored, token 2 is assigned to `%%a` and the remaining part of the input string is assigned to `%%b`.

In your situation:

```
set s=                         2022/11/27 08:50:05    D:\te mp\123.txt

for /F "tokens=2,*" %%a in ("%s%") do set "PREVB=%%b"
echo %prevb%

[OUTPUT]
D:\te mp\123.txt
```

In this example token 1 is ignored, token 2 (time value) - *that is: the last token before the content you need* - is assigned to `%%a` and the remaining part of the input to `%%b`.